# How to add some text before price in product detail page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, price, magento-2.1.3, product-prices

How to add some text before price of product in **product details page** . for

> example:- price - $200.00.

Guys any suggestion from your end.Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make changes in `price-box.js` which is placed at

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-box.js

Make sure you take this js in your custom theme folder and make changes on line number 22 near 
`priceTemplate: '<span class="price"><%- data.formatted %></span>'`

Add your custom text after `<span class="price">`

Some thing like this,

```
priceTemplate: '<span class="price">Price - <%- data.formatted %></span>'
```

Done.

Comment: How to add this text only for old price? It gets added for special price also..