# how i can add text in magento 2 product page price

Tags: magento2, product, price

[image]

> here I want to add

after MRP price:

```
Incl.Tax Rs:1,550.52
```

> in Magento 2 product page

any idea's

i tried this answer but it's showing text for both price(Incl.Tax and Excl.Tax)
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/222750/73525

Answer (score 1):

Override below file

vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\base\templates\product\price\amount\default.phtml

and update based on your requirements.