# how i can display label in only Inclusive of tax price before in magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, products, tax

[image: Inclusive]

*Exclusive word comes for both prices*

> Hi I want to add a label before the product inclusive of price in
>   magento 2
>
> but I added a label  using  this answer

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/222750/73525

**but it displaying label also exclusive price.**

Does anyone help me to fix this issue??

Comment: ARe you use inclusive or exclusive tax?

Comment: I use both ..........